# How can I pass array to url

Tags: reactjs, api, url, saga

I am passing array of categories to url

```
 const data = {
      page: 1,
      limit: limit,
      categories : catIdArray, //["5f3a495c47c36c8e926fc85d"]
    };


props.onPagination(data);
```

but receiving result like this:

```
'{url}/leads?page=1&limit=15&categories=5f3a495c47c36c8e926fc85d'
```

I want to pass this array as an array. Can you please guide me how can i pass array to url ?

Url :

```
const url = `${LEADS}?page=${action.payload.page}&limit=${action.payload.limit}&categories=${categories ? categories : ''}`;
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of your code ?

Comment: I just want to know that how can I send array to url. I have shown console output of url in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the array directly, do stringify it first.

The code will become:

```
const data = {
  page: 1,
  limit: limit,
  categories : JSON.stringify(catIdArray), //["5f3a495c47c36c8e926fc85d"]
};


props.onPagination(data);
```

This will pass the array as you want.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if that answered your question. That motivates us to write more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you only have one item in the array that is `"5f3a495c47c36c8e926fc85d"`

I created this example which has the aaray of categories in the url.
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-drake-4xy0i?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of JavaScript `URLSearchParams` Object which allow you to define a complex chain of *query string*

```js
const data = {
      page: 1,
      limit: 15,
      categories : ["5f3a495c47c36c8e926fc85d"],    
};

const search = new URLSearchParams();
for(let key in data) {
    search.append(key, data[key]);
}

console.log(search.toString());
```